# Toggling div issue in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi All I have a JS function to toggle a div in JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#changer').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "3") {
            $('#divchange').show();
        } else {
            $('#divchange').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

however when the page loads the div doesn't hide when the value isn't 3, if I change the value in the dropdown the div shows and hides accordingly - is there a way around this so I can check the value of #changer on load and if it isn't equal to 3 hide the div?

Comment: `$('#divchange').toggle( this.value == '3' )` would make that a one liner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just trigger the `change` event manually on page load:

```
$('#changer').change(function() {
    // ...
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#changer').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "3") {
            $('#divchange').show();
        } else {
            $('#divchange').hide();
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$('#changer').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put default div hide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#divchange').hide();
});

$(function() {
$('#changer').change(function(){        
    if ($(this).val() == "3") {
        $('#divchange').show();
    } else {
        $('#divchange').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Hope this helps.